# Endpoints not working on WooCommerce checkout page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint

I developing a custom theme. I have an issue on checkout page. When I click on 'Place order' button  the URL of checkout page changing from `http://localhost/sitename/checkout` to look like `http://localhost/sitename/checkout/order-received/390/?key=wc_order_DvIkeeaIUoNFI` if payment-method is 'Cash on delivery' or `http://localhost/sitename/checkout/order-pay/391/?key=wc_order_2TbWibkoOZcxz&order=391` if I choose Internet acquiring payment-method.
But on that pages displayed content of checkout page. I think that endpoints don't work.

Here is what I did to fix that issue:

1. Checked endpoints in **WooCommerce -> Settings -> Advanced**
2. Created new checkout page and deleted old
3. Checked Chrome DevTools Console for JS errors
4. Turned off all plugins except for WooCommerce. Issue still exists.
5. Checked it on another test-site with Storefront theme. Everything works.
6. Checked all default Woocommerce hooks in my custom checkout templates. There are available.
7. Create `web.config`file in site's directory with code which provides on https://woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-endpoints-2-1/
8. Trying to redirect with this code:

```html
<?php

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase' );
function woo_custom_redirect_after_purchase() {
    global $wp;
    if ( is_checkout() && !empty( $wp->query_vars['order-received'] ) ) {
        
        wp_redirect( home_url('/thank-you') );
        exit;
    }

    if ( is_checkout() && !empty( $wp->query_vars['order-pay'] ) ) {
        
        wp_redirect( 'https://secure.wayforpay.com/pay' );
        exit;
    }
}

?>
```

As for me it's bad solution. Because if payment-method is 'Cash on delivery' on thank you page it is not possible to get order data, and if method is 'Internet acquiring' I need to get and transfer order data to acquiring system, but I have a plugin which should do it without my participation. And plugin working on another test-site.

This issue is very popular among junior Wordpress-developers, but there is few information about solving this problem.
I think that endpoints works incorrect, but I don't know how to fix it.
I will be very grateful if you share your own experience in solving the problem or tell me what to look for.

**Updated**

In addition I compared requests and responds in **Chrome->DevTools->Network** between site with Storefront theme and my site. They are the same, but on my site the redirect is not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.
Main issue consist in that my woocommerce doesn't do shortcodes from Console->Pages, so I activated checkout template via page-checkout.php where I get template part form-checkout.php (`get_template_part( 'woocommerce/checkout/form-checkout' );`).
To fix a bug I replaced this string with `echo do_shortcode(['woocommerce_checkout']);`.
Very simple solution that I spent almost 3 days searching for, but even better I learned how wordpress works

Comment: can you give me a little more detail to how do this ? i need to edit form-checkout.php  file ? which part of it should i chanage ? can you give me the code i should change ? i will be apreacite if you give me full code for fixing this issue. thanks alot

Comment: i cant add any thing to checkout page , no new field no new https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77600028/