# woocommerce_before_checkout_form hook is not working with WooCommerce Storefront theme

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, checkout

I want to add something on top of the checkout page , but none of the WooCommerce hooks are working , i dont know what is the problem.

here is my plugin code :

```
function add_custom_checkout_field()
{
    echo '<h2>This is my custom HTML content!</h2>';
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'add_custom_checkout_field', 10);
```

Some other hooks like *woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping* works ok, but *woocommerce_before_checkout_form* is not working at all.

My WooCommerce version is 8.3.1, and the theme is Storefront version 4.5.3.

is this bug or anything ?

Comment: HPOS enabled ? Try disabling and see if this will fix it.

Comment: switch to wordpress post storage (legacy) , and still nothing :(

Comment: @LoicTheAztec , i have pure installation , install wordpress with xampp , install woocommers , install and activate Storefront , make my custom plugin , and thats all i did, may i know your woocommerce and wordpress version ?

Comment: i installed wordpress localy

Comment: @LoicTheAztec can you give me an example file please ? thanks

Comment: @LoicTheAztec  i put it in function.php inside storefront theme , but still nothing ...

Comment: @LoicTheAztec i do all of this thing but still nothing , even if i add some plugin to checkout i cant still see them in checkout page , i downgraded xampp to php 8.1 but still nothing . can you tell me what is your xampp version , and your wordpress core version ? thanks alot

Comment: and debug logs show nothing ....

Comment: Locally,  I don't use XAMPP, but [MAMP PRO](https://documentation.mamp.info/index.html) on a MAC. I also tried your code on a live server, and it also works.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thank you so much for response , i cant understand what is the problem , its from xammp , wordpress , woocommerce or storfront template. there is no info on debug , nothing ... , cant understand how to fix it. thanks again

Comment: @LoicTheAztec  MAMP not works too ... can you please give a simple example so i can test it in my server ? thanks alot

Comment: Are you sure the code is actually running? Add a `var_dump` around the `add_action` call, followed by an `exit` to make sure that that call returns `true`.

Comment: it says bool(true) , but still nothing added to checkout page

Comment: there is no page-checkout inside storefront template , is that because of it ?

Comment: i have new website setup , am i need to do something else after install woocommerce and storefront template ?